# How to delete any element at any particular position in array?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, huffman-code

I have undergone a programming problem where i have to add the first two index of an array and then their sum must be at the first position (removing the two nodes which were added), surely that must result in shifting forward of rest of the array by one index position.
But the problem is it's doing shifts very strangely.
*Please see it carefully, I just have to use Arrays, No other data structure*
Here is the clear picture of what i want. see example :

```
arr[5]= {1,2,3,4,5}
First execution:
{3,3,4,5} //here we added first two elements (1+2=3)
second execution:
(6,4,5) //again added first two elements
third execution:
{10,5}
finally:
{15}
```

My code for that is:

```
    Node *temp;
    Node *array[5]; //actually this array is declared like this {1,2,3,4,5}
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        array[i] = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        array[i]->value = freq[i+1];//this contains {1,2,3,4,5}
        array[i]->sym = arry[i];
        array[i]->left = NULL;
        array[i]->right = NULL;
    printf("%d  ",array[i]->value );
    }
    int j=0,d,t=5;
      while (t>1 )
 {

        temp = array[j];
        printf(" \ncheckOne %d  ",array[j]->value);
        printf("checkTwo %d  \n",array[j+1]->value );
        array[j]->value= temp->value + array[j+1]->value; //
        printf(" checkSumOfOneAndTwo %d  \n",temp->value);
        array[j]=array[j+1];
        array[j]->left=array[j+1];
        array[j]->right=temp;
        array[j]=temp;

            for(d=0;d < t;d++)
        printf(" %d  ",array[d]->value);
        t--; 
        j++;
    }
```

And it's output is :

```
  The Frequencies corresponding to alphabets in Input.txt  files are as follows 
: a  b  c  d  e  
1  2  3  4  5   
checkOne 1  checkTwo 2  
 checkSumOfOneAndTwo 3  
 3   2   3   4   5   
checkOne 2  checkTwo 3  
 checkSumOfOneAndTwo 5  
 3   5   3   4   
checkOne 3  checkTwo 4  
 checkSumOfOneAndTwo 7  
 3   5   7   
checkOne 4  checkTwo 5  
 checkSumOfOneAndTwo 9  
 3   5
```

I am beginner to programming. could any one please tell me what is the mistake and how to fix ? (I am obliged to implement it just using array-so No Linked lists, heaps etc.)

Comment: `array[j]->value= temp->value + array[j+1]->value;` j+1 --> 5 ,Array Out-of-Bounds.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY So what could be  the solution of it ? please see my output corresponding to this input, what can be done to solve it ?thanks

Comment: It would be easy to handle array as stack.

Comment: But how to do that ? any piece of code helping me , but i have to do with arrays only. thanks for explaining me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This small piece of code is a problem by itself:

```
    array[j]=array[j+1];
    array[j]->left=array[j+1];
```

After executing the above code, you have a node whose 'left' pointer is pointing to itself.

I would start by fixing this to begin with.

**UPDATE:**

In order to build the Huffman tree efficiently, you should use a binary heap (minimum at top) rather than an array. At each iteration, you should extract the root twice, sum the two nodes into one, and push the result back into the heap.

**UPDATE #2:**

If you insist on using an array rather than a binary heap, then you have a basic conceptual error in your code:

Your array must be sorted min-to-max during **the entire execution**.

You begin with a sorted array, but you are not making sure that it remains sorted at the end of each iteration.

In short, after summing up the first two elements, you **cannot** simply put the result as the first node in the array. Instead, you must "propagate" that node to the right place within the array, in order to keep it sorted min-to-max.

Failing to do so will may result with a working code, but an incorrect implementation of Huffman encoding/decoding.

**UPDATE #3:**

The code below is just a general framework of how you should build your Huffman tree, if you insist on using an array rather than a binary heap. I have not verified it.

```
    // Create a new node, whose children are the first two nodes in the array
    temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->value = array[0]->value + array[1]->value;
    temp->left  = array[0];
    temp->right = array[1];

    array_size--;

    // Push the new node into the array, and move all elements 1 entry backwards
    array[0] = temp;
    for (int k=1; k<array_size; k++)
    {
        array[k] = array[k+1];
    }

    // Move the new node forward, until the array is properly sorted (min-to-max)
    for (int k=1; k<array_size; k++)
    {
        if (array[k-1]->value < array[k]->value)
            break;
        temp = array[k-1];
        array[k-1] = array[k];
        array[k] = temp;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want me to write down the code for you? I can just send you a Huffman encoder/decoder in C++ if you want...

Comment: If i do array[j]=array[j+1];
        array[j]->left=temp;  
        array[j]->right=array[j+1]; then also outout is wrong :: a  b  c  d  e  
1  2  3  4  5   
checkOne 1  checkTwo 2  
 checkSumOfOneAndTwo 3  
 3   2   3   4   5   
checkOne 2  checkTwo 3  
 checkSumOfOneAndTwo 5  
 3   5   3   4   
checkOne 3  checkTwo 4  
 checkSumOfOneAndTwo 7  
 3   5   7   
checkOne 4  checkTwo 5  
 checkSumOfOneAndTwo 9  
 3   5   
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: i want in c language (if you have) but i don't have to use Linkedlists,Heap etc. Only using arrays. Even then you can forward me for refrence at shekhar.paris@gmail.com thanks.

Comment: I have my own implementation (top to bottom) in C++. It includes the implementation of a binary heap (see my updated answer above), which is really quite simple. Here is the link: http://www.Planet-Source-Code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=9737&lngWId=3. See the enclosed Word file for documentation.

Comment: Do you know the way in which i want to do it ? Actually i am strictly obliged to do using array, please help me, I can give you the output or i can send you  the code by email, you can correct it and relpy me the correct one, Is it possible ? please giveme your email, if yes ?

Comment: Please see my updated answer; I believe that you have a conceptual error in your Huffman implementation, even if we fix your code to work somehow. You MUST keep the array sorted min-to-max after every iteration.

Comment: I know that i need a sorted array, that i will do once if my logic of adding two nodes and shifting position is correct , i will use qsort() for it's simple once if the adding and shifting node parts is solved, I have sent you my flies on your barakman@yahoo.com , please help me if possible, thanks barak

Comment: You MUST create (malloc) a new node every time you sum two nodes into one. Please see update #3 in my answer above.

Comment: why do decrement the array_size-- ?(It should be incremented i think ++)because if we have to start fromt he first two nodes and then we have to go the next nodes so , it must be incremented i think, AM i right ?? see below please:    temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->value = array[j]->value + array[j+1]->value;
    temp->left  = array[j];
    temp->right = array[j+1]; j++;

Comment: My `array_size` variable is equivalent to your `t` variable. This is how the algorithm works: You start off with an array containing only the leaves of the tree. At each iteration, you create a new node in the tree, take two elements out of the array, set the new node to be their parent, and insert the new node into the array. So at each iteration you have 1 element less in the array. At the end of the algorithm, you have a full Huffman tree, and the array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int stack_size = 5;
    int sp = stack_size;
    int *stack = malloc(stack_size * sizeof(int));//int stack[5];
    int i;
    for(i=stack_size; i>0 ;--i){
        stack[--sp] = i;//push
    }
    //print stack
    printf("{ " );
    for(i = sp;i<stack_size;++i)
        printf("%d ", stack[i]);
    printf("}\n");

    int t = stack_size;
    for(t=stack_size;t > 1;--t){
        int first, second;
        first = stack[sp++];//pop
        second = stack[sp++];//pop
        stack[--sp] = first + second;//push

        printf("{ " );//now stack print 
        for(i = sp;i<stack_size;++i)
            printf("%d ", stack[i]);
        printf("}\n");
    }

    free(stack);
    return 0;
}
/* result
{ 1 2 3 4 5 }
{ 3 3 4 5 }
{ 6 4 5 }
{ 10 5 }
{ 15 }
*/
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but what if i  have to sort at each addition of two smallest elements ?

Comment: @user3085082 I do not know the meaning of what you say, but the sort, can the array at any time if necessary.

Comment: @user3085082 I think that it implement the heap using an array if you need a sort every time you add an element to the array.